# Return custom (our own ) Error messages and Warnings from a sybase stored procedure/trigger to a vb6 form using ado

Tags: vb6, ado, sybase

I am using sybase as back end. vb6 as front end, with ado as data model. In sybase, I have a insert trigger ( the trigger will fire when an insert is made to the table). I am invoking the stored procedure/trigger, in VB6 using ADO. I want to display some custom  error messages ( that are written in sybase sp/trigger)  in the vb6 form. How to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RAISERROR error-number [ format-string ] [, arg-list] 


RAISERROR 99999 'Invalid entry for this 
column: %1!', @val
```